# code Android Click an event two buttons

Tags: android, button, android-imagebutton

I am new in the Android I want a full example as in the picture Please help my thank you.

[image]

Comment: Goto google .How to show Toast in Android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202006/android-have-toast-appear-on-button-click

Comment: not sure if it's a good ux.

Comment: Do you specifically only want to show the toast if both buttons are pressed at the same time? Or if any of the buttons are pressed?

Comment: Yes, I want to show toast if pressed two buttons at the same time

Answer (score 1):

### The multitouch part

So I've been digging around in this subject and come across some things to keep in mind.

```
android:splitMotionEvents="true"
```

The above setting needs to be set.

Also what you'll probably want to read about is Android Multitouch.

I won't be able to give you an example from scratch for such a broad question but I'll send you some useful links to get you started.

---

[1. Android work multitouch button [StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5346148/2975371)

[2. How to code for multitouch [StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231216/2975371)

[3. Handling Multi-Touch Gestures [developer.android.com]](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)

[4. How to use Multi-touch in Android 2 [zdnet.com]](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/)

[5. How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 2, Building the Touch example [zdnet.com]](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/)

---

I would assume you are looking for something like the 5th link. Again, I won't post that code here for the sake of it.

### The toast part

So after you've implemented the first above part you simply need to add the following code to that event (where you've checked that both buttons are clicked at the same time).

```
// All of this inside your OnClick-event 

    // If (both buttons are clicked) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show this message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    if(toast != null) 
        toast.show();

// End your OnClick-event.
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I need an example of a full pressed two buttons at the same time As in the picture I would understand that a good example of

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean button1_clicked=false, button2_clicked=false;

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1_clicked =true;

            if(button1_clicked && button2_clicked){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                button1_clicked =false;
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button1_clicked =false;
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2_clicked =true;

            if(button1_clicked && button2_clicked){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                button2_clicked =false;
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button2_clicked =false;
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

I Think this handler helps to reset the variable after 500 milli second.

Comment: I can not squeeze buttons in a same time in the Code

Answer (score 0):

I used this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private long start;
private long finish;
private boolean ciclo=true;
private Activity activity;
private boolean show;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity = this;
}

public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    new MultiplyTask().execute();

    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button:
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

public class MultiplyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(show)
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ciclo = true;
            show=false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        while(ciclo)
        {
            if(Math.abs(finish-start)<50)
            {
                show=true;
                ciclo=false;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

}
```

And the layout has to be like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="69dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is an error out of the application when running

Comment: @rokrol are you sure? I tested the app and it worked!

Comment: @rokrol what's the problem? Does it crash?

Comment: The application appears, and then goes out

Comment: @rokrol that's very strange...post the manifest. Did you copy well?

Comment: Yes good copy.Can the problem be targetSdk .  I use targetSdk 4.0 .

Comment: @rokrol post the manifest in your question, I use 7.1.1 android

Comment: It has been used Sdk 7.1 and 4.0.3 and 4.0 But there is the same problem comes out of the application

Comment: @rokrol do you open the app and then does it crash?

Comment: Yes .This is who got

Comment: @rokrol I didn't understand your answer